# Limit the number of characters in swift

Tags: swift

I have created the following code where I have an outlet name password, when the user enters a password, I seek to have a limit of more than 5 characters and less than 15. How can I impose this limit within this code?

```
    guard let password = password.text, password.count > 6 else {
        self.password.showError(true)
        return
    }

    guard (password == confirmPassword.text) else {
        self.confirmPassword.showError(true)
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
 guard let password = password.text, password.count > 5 , password.count < 15 else {
    self.password.showError(true)
    return
}
```

or

```
guard (6...15).contains(password.text!.count) else {
    self.password.showError(true)
    return
}
```

Also you can use `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate method of the `UITextField` to limit the count check [This](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-a-uitextfield-or-uitextview)